# C# code cannot see file even though it exists

Tags: c#

I'm trying to launch the MS NLB manager(nlbmgr.exe) in my code, but the program says it doesn't exist, even though it is there.  I've checked file permissions and I have access, but it still doesn't work.

Here is the code I am using:

```
if (File.Exists(@"C:\Windows\system32\nlbmgr.exe"))
{
    ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
    info.FileName = @"C:\Windows\system32\nlbmgr.exe";
    info.UseShellExecute = true;
    info.CreateNoWindow = true;
    info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;
    info.RedirectStandardInput = false;
    info.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
    info.RedirectStandardError = false;

    System.Diagnostics.Process p = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(info);
}
```

If I copy-paste the path into a command prompt or Start -> Run, it works fine.

I saw other posts mention the sysnative folder, but that doesn't exist on my system.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at this about the [file system redirector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

It seems as though your path is being redirected to C:\Windows\SysWOW64\nlbmgr.exe the sysnative thing stops this from happening.  This won't actually exist on your system it is just virtual.  Try changing your path to `@"C:\Windows\Sysnative\nlbmgr.exe"` which will cause the call to actually get directed to `"C:\Windows\System32\nlbmgr.exe"` which is the correct path you want.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I tried that and it worked.  I had seen the sysnative mentioned in another post, but thought they were referring to an actual directory, which I wasn't seeing in Windows Explorer.  I didn't realize this was a "virtual directory" the code translated.  Thanks for the help, working now.

Answer (score 0):

Just taking a guess, but is this a 32bit application trying to access this folder?  I think what might be happening is how is redirecting the FS to `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`.  There are some examples here in C# in the wiki section:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187(v=vs.85).aspx